# Hide/remove USB mode pop up window while NOOK debugging

Tags: debugging, nook

I'm debugging my Android app with NOOK color device.

When I connected USB to NOOK Color, the Window "USB Mode" with text "You may now safely move files from your PC to NOOKcolor..." pops up and BLOCKS any interaction with device.

I can run my app, but I can't interact with it until I disconnect USB. If I disconnect USB, I obviously can't debug any more (I'm using ADB to debug my app with Eclipse). How can I remove this silly window???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eject any mounted USB drives associated with your NOOK (internal and external storage) and the dialog goes away.

Tom

Comment: And on Ubuntu 14.04, if they're not mounted, mount them and then unmount them.

Answer (score 0):

From the Mac you can go to finder and click the eject button for the device. adb will still recognize the nook.
similarly From windows click on safely remove hardware from the systray.